# How can I use a generator to run my Neural Network model?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a neural network model that run perfectly, but I am using a very large data and I try to use a generator to run the model, but it gives me the following error:

```
"UnimplementedError: 

  File "<ipython-input-63-352f4097b60f>", line 146, in <module>
    validation_steps = len(df_valid)/batch_size, shuffle=True)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1297, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 265, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 973, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight, reset_metrics=reset_metrics)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 264, in train_on_batch
    output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py", line 311, in train_on_batch
    output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py", line 252, in _process_single_batch
    training=training))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py", line 166, in _model_loss
    per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(targets[i], outs[i])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\losses.py", line 221, in call
    return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\losses.py", line 978, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
    y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 4530, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
    target = cast(target, 'int64')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 1571, in cast
    return math_ops.cast(x, dtype)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 704, in cast
    x = gen_math_ops.cast(x, base_type, name=name)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 2211, in cast
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

UnimplementedError: Cast string to int64 is not supported [Op:Cast] name: loss/dense_38_loss/Cast/
```

What is wrong with the generator?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.utils import np_utils
import pandas as pd

batch_size = 64
# Read in the training and validation data
df_train = pd.read_csv(r'C:\train.txt', sep='|', encoding='latin-1', 
low_memory=False)
df_valid = pd.read_csv(r'C:\valid.txt', sep='|', encoding='latin-1', 
low_memory=False)

print('training rows:', len(df_train))
print('validation rows:', len(df_valid))

def generator(df,vocab_size,batch_size, tokenizer,input_encoder,onehot):
            n_examples = len(df)
            number_of_batches = n_examples / batch_size
            counter  = 0
            while 1:
                            start_index = counter  * batch_size
                            end_index = start_index + batch_size
                            X_out1 = np.array(([batch_size, n_examples, vocab_size]), dtype=int)
                            if counter > number_of_batches + 1:
                                            # reshuffle dataframe and start over
                                            df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
                                            counter  = 0
                            counter  += 1

                            X_out1 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df.iloc[start_index: end_index]['var1'])
                            X_out1 = sequence.pad_sequences(X_out1, maxlen=200)
                            X_out2 = df.iloc[start_index: end_index][['var2','var3']]
                            X_out2 = input_encoder.transform(df.iloc[start_index: end_index][[ 'var2','var3']])
                            X_out2 = onehot.transform(df.iloc[start_index: end_index][[ 'var2','var3']])
                            Y_out = df.iloc[start_index: end_index]['code']
                            yield [X_out1, X_out2], [Y_out]

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_train['var1'])

input_encoder = MultiColumnLabelEncoder()
train_X2=df_train[['var2','var3']]
valid_X2 =df_valid[['var2','var3']]
input_encoder.fit(train_X2)

onehot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,categories='auto')
onehot.fit(train_X2)

code_type = 'code'                              
train_labels = df_train[code_type] 
valid_labels = df_valid[code_type] 

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
labels = set(df_train[code_type].tolist() + df_valid[code_type].tolist()) 
label_encoder.fit(list(labels)) 
n_classes = len(set(labels)) 
print('n_classes = %s' % n_classes) 


input_text = Input(shape=(200,), dtype='int32', name='input_text')
meta_input = Input(shape=(2,), name='meta_input')
embedding = Embedding(input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, 
          output_dim=300, 
          input_length=200)(input_text)

lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128, 
              dropout=0.5, 
              recurrent_dropout=0.5, 
              return_sequences=True),
         merge_mode='concat')(embedding)
pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(lstm)
dropout = Dropout(0.5)(pool)
text_output = Dense(n_codes, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(dropout)

output = concatenate([text_output, meta_input])
output = Dense(n_codes, activation='relu')(output)

main_output = Dense(n_codes, activation='softmax', name='main_output')(output)

model = Model(inputs=[input_text,meta_input], outputs=[output])
optimer = Adam(lr=.001)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
  loss='binary_crossentropy', 
  metrics=['accuracy'])


# Generators
train_generator = generator(df_train,vocab_size,batch_size, tokenizer,input_encoder,onehot)
validation_generator = generator(df_valid,vocab_size,batch_size, tokenizer,input_encoder,onehot)


model.summary()

model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator, 
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      epochs=20,steps_per_epoch = len(df_train)/batch_size,
      validation_steps = len(df_valid)/batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: I have added the entire error message.

Comment: *"UnimplementedError: Cast string to int64 is not supported ..."* sounds like your data is string, not numeric. If this is text data, you need to do some preprocessing to somehow convert it to numbers, e.g. word-vector. Please see the many good tutorials on text preprocessing.

Comment: @borfo No [mcve], though?

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding the LabelEncoder in the generator. But now I have a new issue: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected meta_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (7668,). It will be great if you can help me with this error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the problem is a type mismatch due to the use of a CSV file. A number (the labels) is read from the CSV as a string and it's not converted to an int automatically.

This is the expected outputs (labels) which you read from the CSV:

```
Y_out = df.iloc[start_index: end_index]['code']
```

It is probably an string, try printing `Y_out.dtypes` to confirm.

Your model's output (prediction) is a one-hot encoded label which is an `int64`; the type mismatch happens when TF is trying to calculate the loss value subtracting a number from a string.